# Problems with shared_ptr<T[]> wrapping a dynamic array

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I wanted to replace some raw pointers in my class with a `std::shared_ptr` so that I don't have to worry when I create copies of that class. But the raw pointers point to a dynamic array. Using a shared_ptr with dynamic arrays is possible when you give it a custom deleter, e. g. `default_delete<T[]>`.

But I get a big error list as soon as I try to assign a new value to that field, even on construction.

Here's a minimal code sample:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> shared_ptr<T[]> make_shared_array(size_t size)
{
  return shared_ptr<T[]>(new T[size], default_delete<T[]>());
}

struct Foo
{
  shared_ptr<char[]> field;
};

int main()
{
  Foo a;
  // This line produces the error.
  a.field = make_shared_array<char>(256);

  return 0;
}
```

---

**NB:** Yes, I know that I could/should `vector` instead of dynamic arrays. But their performance is not the same. I do some heavy image processing and the arrays hold the pixels. On less than VGA resolution the processing time increased from 8 to 11 s. That's quite a lot.

---

**Update:** Of course I can provide the errors here. I just didn't know if I should clutter the problem description with it. But here it is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(754) : error C2664: 'std::_Ptr_base<_Ty>::_Reset0' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'char (*)[]'
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=char []
>           ]
>           Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::_Resetp0<_Ux>(_Ux *,std::_Ref_count_base *)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=char [],
>               _Ux=char
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::_Resetp0<_Ux>(_Ux *,std::_Ref_count_base *)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=char [],
>               _Ux=char
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(494) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::_Resetp<_Ux,_Dx>(_Ux *,_Dx)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=char [],
>               _Ux=char,
>               _Dx=std::default_delete
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(494) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::_Resetp<_Ux,_Dx>(_Ux *,_Dx)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=char [],
>               _Ux=char,
>               _Dx=std::default_delete
>           ]
>           problem.cpp(9) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr>(_Ux *,_Dx)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=char [],
>               T=char,
>               _Ux=char,
>               _Dx=std::default_delete
>           ]
>           problem.cpp(9) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr>(_Ux *,_Dx)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=char [],
>               T=char,
>               _Ux=char,
>               _Dx=std::default_delete
>           ]
>           problem.cpp(21) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> make_shared_array(size_t)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=char []
>           ]

Comment: Would you, perchance, share this "big error list?"

Comment: I hear this "their performance is not the same" quite often, can you show some evidence? I have tried quite hard, testing all kinds of operations, but all my results always result in both being of exactly the same speed...

Comment: if using vector::reserve when initializing the vector (or simply initializing it to a fixed size) the performance should be "close enough to same"

Comment: I would expect a `std::vector` to perform better (unless you make copies).

Comment: Dare I suggest an edit of the title here @primfactor. "How to wrap an array in a shared_ptr" or something like that. It would make searching for this answer easier.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: What I did is replace the core pixel data pointer with `vector<unsigned char>` and fixed all parameter types so that it compiled again. Visually it showed the same filter result, but the performance dropped.

Comment: @eladidan: I'm quite sure I had the `.reserve(…)` in, but maybe I could give it another try.

Comment: @primfaktor: That hardly qualifies as evidence, it leaves so much room for other mistakes; e.g. following this verbatim it could even be that foo(T*) got changed to foo(vector<T>)...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Well, only the necessary stuff. I even tried to be smart wrt. performance and pass `&the_vector[0]` to called functions . This had the benefit of not having to change everything function that before expected a pointer.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, @eladidan: Ok, I guess I can use vector than. Since my last test things have gotten tidier and the transition was not that much work. Storing in `vector` instead of raw pointer, cool. Passing  `vector` and using `vector`'s `operator[]`, not cool. So I will use the `&the_vector[0]` trick. A little code with timings on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DNSqGnqK). Thanks for making me try again.

Comment: `vector<BYTE> paddedInput(paddedInput_, paddedInput_ + (nWidth + 2 * nPatch) * (nHeight + 2 * nPatch));
delete [] paddedInput_;` in the `vector` case you duplicate the data.  Change how it is produced from being a `BYTE*` to being produced as a `vector<BYTE>` instead of making a copy of it.

Comment: @Yakk: Well that had virtually no impact, as I expected. Because that step is a one time operation versus the linked code which is deeply nested like “whole image” > “search window”. So 4 for loops deep at worst.

Comment: If you really need such a shared pointer: Have you thought about using `make_shared<vector<char>>(256)`? It has a nice memory layout similar to the layout of daramarak's solution due to the make_shared-optimization. If you access each element through that shared_ptr, there will be an unnecessary level of indirection but nothing stops you from working with iterators.

Comment: @primfaktor: Yes, `&the_vector[0]` has the benefit that you can feed your function with vector data as well as manually allocated arrays. But what stopped you from using references to vectors as function parameters? Also, you might want to google for `array_ref`. It's not yet standard but quite handy and similar to a pointer. But it's a little smarter than a pointer because it knows the array's size and implicitly convertes from a vector, for example.

Comment: @sellibitze: See the [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/DNSqGnqK) on the types, signatures and timings. Passing as `const vector` reference is just non-negligibly slower.

Comment: @primfaktor: Sorry, I can't make much sense of the code fragments you posted on pastebin.

Comment: @sellibitze: Well these are all the differences. What is not shown is the access inside *ExtractPatch* via `from[some_index]`. In the first two versions this will be dereferencing a dynamic array (which lives inside `vector` in the 2nd version). In the 3rd version, the `vector::operator[]` will be called. And that must be the (source of) the overhead.

Comment: @primfaktor `vector::operator[]` will simply do the normal pointer indexing off its internal pointer; `from[some_index]`. It should get inlined so there should be zero overhead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution you suggest is possible, but you will lose the size of the array:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> shared_ptr<T> make_shared_array(size_t size)
{
   return shared_ptr<T>(new T[size], default_delete<T[]>());
}

struct Foo
{
  shared_ptr<char> field;
};

int main()  
{
  Foo a;
  a.field = make_shared_array<char>(256);

 return 0;
}
```

What I have done here is to let the array decay into a pointer. As long as the deleter is  an array deleter it should behave correctly.

To prevent this loss of size, and if you cannot use boost::shared_array as suggested, I would suggest to encapsulate this information in your own shared_array class.

Comment: Ok, now that's a simple solution. Although I don't understand that there's `unique_ptr<T[]>` which does everything automatically, but `shared_ptr` does not do that and makes me provide a deleter *but I must not say `<T[]>`?* Strange.

Comment: Why is it strange? `shared_ptr` isn't specialized for arrays, so just as `shared_ptr<T>` expects a pointer to a `T`, `shared_ptr<T[]>` expects a pointer to `T[]` i.e. a pointer to an array of `T`, and you're giving it a pointer to `T`. Ain't gonna work. `unique_ptr` has a specialization to handle the case, and so doesn't interpret `unique_ptr<T[]>` as a pointer to an array, but that doesn't happen by magic, it requires a partial specialization of the template.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist that you should not use `std::vector`, Boost has a [`boost::shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) that works as a smart pointer to manage a dynamically allocated array of object.

`shared_ptr` is not designed to handle an *array*. Since `shared_array` is available, why try to use `shared_ptr` on *array* s?

Comment: Because we don't use Boost. :-/

Comment: @primfaktor why not start using it?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Because that's also a political/company decision which I cannot take.

Answer (score 3):

If you specified the deleter then you don't use `T[]` in the template argument. Just change `T[]` to `T`:

```
template <typename T> shared_ptr<T> make_shared_array(size_t size)
{
  return shared_ptr<T>(new T[size], default_delete<T[]>());
}

struct Foo
{
  shared_ptr<char> field;
};
```

Comment: @BlueBug `(*field)[idx]`

Comment: @0x499602D2 access violation  :(

Comment: @BlueBug Sorry, do `field.get()[idx]`. :)

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` is specialized for array types so you can use `T[]` with it and it will know that it's still just storing a `T*`. `std::shared_ptr` is not specialized this way and so a `shared_ptr<T[]>` will try to store a pointer to an array, `T(*)[]`, which won't work very well with the conventions around raw arrays in C++. Not to mention that an array of unknown size is an incomplete type, and `shared_ptr` will eventually need a complete type.

You mention knowing that `std::vector` should be a better solution but doesn't perform as well. It should perform just fine and you'd probably be better off figuring out why it doesn't.

Comment: The discussion in the comments of the question expands on that a little. Or you can directly go to the [code in question](http://pastebin.com/DNSqGnqK). But why should it definitely be equally as good? Doesn't `vector` encapsulate a raw pointer thus adding complexity? How can (however minimal) **added** complexity for the general case be as fast as (specifically and) manually optimized code?

Comment: But if you show me where my thinking is wrong, I'm always eager to learn.

Comment: +1 for [array_ref<T>](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3334.html#classstd_1_1array__ref). Although I'd additionally want the cleanup capability of `shared_ptr`.